# puppet style, what does "prefer metaparameters to relationship declarations" *mean*?

Tags: puppet

Looking at the [Relationship Declarations](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/style_guide.html#relationship-declarations) section in the Puppet Style Guide about the '->' arrows, where 'x->y' means that y requires x to be installed before y, it says:

```
When possible, you should prefer metaparameters to relationship declarations.
```

that's a lot of syllables. Is that saying that you should prefer this

```
file { "/home/${user}/.ssh":
    require => User[$user],
    ...
}
```

and *not* use the arrows like this?

```
User[$user] -> file { "/home/${user}/.ssh":
    ...
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what it is saying. prefer `before`, `require`, `notify`, etc rather than chaining arrows.

Comment: Why are those preferred? If they're preferred, why are the arrows an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file { "/home/${user}/.ssh":
    require => User[$user],
    ...
}
```

1.The above code even works with different manifests, when they are part of same catalog. So if you use metaparameters you have less work when you get a modification in future(unfortunately).

2.Chaining arrows is best used for [Resource collectors](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_collectors.html), when you have to make relationship more than one resource, you can have this instead of putting require/before in all the resources.